# Remove certain facebook posts with javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm totally new to javascript. I'm trying to hide certain facebook posts. I found this code:

```
 var posts = document.getElementsByClassName("uiStreamMessage");

 for(var i=0; i<posts.length; i++){
 if(posts[i].innerHTML.indexOf("test") != -1){ posts[i].parentNode.removeChild(posts[i])             };
 }
```

So, every post which contains the string 'test' is supposed to be hidden, right ?
It doesn't work for me. Maybe facebook changed it's class names and "uiStreamMessage" isn't correct anymore ?

I hope you guys can help me ! Excuse me for my bad english ! 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine Facebook changes their DOM classes from time to time, so that might be the reason.

This worked for me though:

```
var posts = document.getElementsByClassName("userContentWrapper");

for(var i=0; i<posts.length; i++){  
    if(posts[i].innerHTML.indexOf("test") != -1){ 
       var parent = posts[i].parentNode; 
       parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent)             
     };
}
```

This is how my DOM looks, I'd be cool to see if yours is any different.

[image]

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't remove anything for me. I replaced "test" with "High", since the top post I see on my facebook is currently a picture with the text "Shuffle'n in High Heels !!!". Any idea on what I'm doing wrong ? Thanks !

Comment: First, How exactly are you testing it? Where are you pasting the code?

Comment: Also, how does your DOM look?

Comment: I did a chrome extension and I'm testing it by clicking the addon button (I added a window.alert at the end so I can see if the code is even being executed).

Comment: So you get the window.alert and your DOM is the same as mine. What is the result of `posts`? What happens if you `console.log` it?

Comment: Also, maybe you want to paste the code to your extension, just to get the whole picture of what's going on...

Comment: Yes, I get the window.alert. As I said I'm totally new to javascript and I don't really know how to check the results nor how to console.log it. Yes sure, give me a sec

Comment: Just do `console.log(posts);` after you set the `posts` variable. What's the result of that?

Comment: BTW, it seems that you are querying the HTML on your `test.html` page and not the HTML in your Facebook page.. that might be your error. I'm sure there's a way to interact with the DOM of the page you're in though.

Comment: I couldn't see anything in the console (Control -Shift -J). So I think you are right with the test.html. I don't even need an html-file, I just did it like in the sample (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted). Is there any way to call the js file without any html-file so it queries my facebook page ?

Comment: I think you have to do something like this: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: Oh, that looks really complicated to me :o How did you get it working in the first place ?

Comment: I just copy pasted it in the console. That's the cool thing about JavaScript, you can just play around with any web page by opening the console and write code in it.

Comment: Yup that's really cool thank you. I added the content scripts to my manifest.json file: pastebin.com/raw.php?i=bsTUVLAi  It's kinda working now. The problem is that the js is only being executed when you open the facebook in a new tab or when you refresh with ctrl + r. I need it working all the time though (when I navigate on the facebook page - for example by a click on the facebook logo). I might open a new topic. Thank you !